# Recrear la función split en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, funciones, split

Necesito ayuda a resolver este ejercicio ya que me estoy dando la cabeza contra el escritorio desde hoy ajajajajaj, hasta el momento lo que tengo hecho es lo siguiente:

```
function split([string]) {
  let array2 = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= string.length; i++) {
    array2 += string.shift()
  }
  console.log(array2);
}
```

Lo que tengo en la cabeza es hacer con el shift que saque el primer valor del string y lo vaya acumulando en array2 pero sin sumarlos, sino, separándolos, pero bueno, cuando lo pruebo en la consola me sale que string.shift no es una función

Comment: Hola amigo, lo siento se que eres nuevo usuario pero aqui no te resolvemos tareas, el sitio no es `Yahoo` ni `google`, sugiero que hagas este tipo de preguntas relacionadas con tareas ya sea en `yahoo` o `google`, segun las normas del sitio: [ask], dicen que una buena pregunta no solo deberia tener un ejemplo minimo y verificable de codigo, sino que ademas, expresar el problema claramente y mostrar aquello que haz intentado para resolverlo, en tu caso solo nos planteas lo siguiente: "Hola tengo esta tarea, por favor resuelvanla", este tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas en stackoverflow

Comment: No es que directamente la pregunta no pueda ser respondida, pero en si debes mostrarnos aquello que haz intentado **mediante codigo** pues ahora mismo no hay evidencia de que hayas intentado nada, si cumples las condiciones del sitio y tratas primero de resolver el ejercicio podremos ayudarte, solamente tendrias que editar la pregunta y poner aquello que intentaste y los errores que tuviste al tratar de hacer "X" cosa. de esta manera los usuarios luego te daran una respuesta a la pregunta.

Comment: De todas maneras te voy a dar una pista que facilitara mucho las cosas, ten en cuenta que en javascript puedes acceder a las partes de un string como si fuera un arreglo, tambien recuerda que el ejercicio pide que no se use esa funcion mas no ninguna otra, asi que tambien puedes usar otros metodos de los strings: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String

Comment: Un array inicial vacío y luego recorres el string con un forEach que haga un push de cada elemento al array. Al final retorna el array ya llenado. No es tan difícil, haz un intento y nos compartes tu intento y tus dudas si es que las hay.

Comment: Ahi reformule la pregunta, gracias por sus recomendaciones! Disculpen si les parece una boludes, recién estoy arrancando en esto, saludos y gracias!

Comment: No estas muy lejos, sin embargo el simbolo `+=` **NO** funciona con arrays. ademas `shift` es un metodo de `arrays` no de strings. supongo que en una media hora mas o por ahi si nadie mas ha dado una respuesta publico la mia, primero quiero dejar que pienses un rato mas, no estas lejos.

Comment: Utiliza [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push) para agregar un nuevo elemento a tu array. Aprovecha que estás en el `for` para "empujar" el elemento `i` del string (`string[i]`)

Comment: Lo puede hacer, muchisimas gracias a los dos! Lo hice utilizando la funcion string.charAt(i) en el push del array vacio

Answer (score 0):

Un `split` en javascript retorna un array dado:
1.- Una Cadena
2.- un Separdor
3.- un limite(opcional)

Para lo cual tu función debe de recibir estos tres parámetros:

```
function split(cadena,separador='',limite=-1)
```

donde si la cadena es exactamente igual a vacio, pusheamos `cadena[i]`

```
if(separador===''){
   resp.push(cadena[i])
}
```

Caso contrario buscamos el separador en nuestra cadena:

```
if(separador===cadena[i])
```

Si encontramos nuestro separador, consultamos si nuestro `limite` aun nos permite insertar resultados

```
limite==-1 || limite > resp.length
```

Si el resultado es positivo insertamos nuestro `concat`:

```
resp.push(concat)
```

Al final de todo, al finalizar nuestro `for` volvemos a consultar si `concat` tiene algun valor, y si aun no tenemos nuestro limite al maximo:

```
if(concat!="" && (limite==-1 || limite > resp.length))
```

Quizá el código esta **muy oloroso** pero te funcionara, como lo podemos apreciar en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
function split(cadena,separador='',limite=-1){
    const resp=[];
    let concat="";
    for(let i=0;i<cadena.length;i++){
        if(separador===''){
            resp.push(cadena[i])
        }else{
            if(separador===cadena[i]){
                limite==-1 || limite > resp.length ? resp.push(concat) : i=cadena.length ;
                concat="";
            }
            else{
                concat+=cadena[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if(concat!="" && (limite==-1 || limite > resp.length)){
        resp.push(concat);
    }
    return resp;
}
//comparaciones
let cadena="hola a todos en el mundo";
console.log(split(cadena),cadena.split(''));
console.log(split(cadena,' '),cadena.split(' '));
console.log(split(cadena,' ',2),cadena.split(' ',2));
```